# In Jest, Are Defining Global Variables the Same as if They are Defined in BeforeAll?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

When writing unit tests with **Jest**. Why would you use *beforeAll* over simply assigning value straight to global variables or vice versa?

For example, what's the difference between the following two snippets?

**Snippet 1**

```
const mock = { key1: 'val1', key2: 'val2' };

describe('Test Cases', () => {
  test('Case 1', () => {
    // tests that use mock variable
  });

  test('Case 2', () => {
    // more tests that use mock variable
  });
});
```

**Snippet 2**

```
const mock = {};

beforeAll(() => {
  mock.key1 = 'val1';
  mock.key2 = 'val2';
});

describe('Test Cases', () => {
  test('Case 1', () => {
    // tests that use mock variable
  });

  test('Case 2', () => {
    // more tests that use mock variable
  });
});
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your example, it does not make any difference. There are cases when it does make sense, however, to use *beforeAll*: if you have asynchronous code, functions that return promises.

If you return a promise from the *beforeAll* callback, you can test the value that the promise eventually resolves to easily in a test.

Quoting from the [Jest documentation](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/setup-teardown.html#one-time-setup):

> In some cases, you only need to do setup once, at the beginning of a file. This can be especially bothersome when the setup is asynchronous, so you can't just do it inline. Jest provides *beforeAll* and afterAll to handle this situation.
>   For example, if both *initializeCityDatabase* and *clearCityDatabase* returned promises, and the city database could be reused between tests, we could change our test code to:

```
beforeAll(() => {
    return initializeCityDatabase();
});

afterAll(() => {
    return clearCityDatabase();
});

test('city database has Vienna', () => {
    expect(isCity('Vienna')).toBeTruthy();
});

test('city database has San Juan', () => {
    expect(isCity('San Juan')).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Comment: That makes sense!
Thank you sir!

Comment: So, this means that no tests will run until the promise resolves -- Jest is handling this behind the scenes somehow. Yes?